# How to model the effects of diffraction for a convex lens?

Tags: optics, diffraction, lenses, interferometry

I am using a convex lens in a wavefront-measuring interferometer for testing microscope objectives, where the lens images the exit-pupil of the objective onto my camera. It is my understanding that the effects of diffraction from the convex lens will have some influence on my interferogram, especially around its edges. How can I actually take these effects into consideration?